# How do you extract the numbers from a text file while also stating the line each appears on? (Python)

Tags: python, text, extract

I need to know how to extract a number from a text file while also having it tell me what line the number is on. But i need it to paste the output to a new text file

Program:

```py
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        for i in words:
            for letter in i:
                if(letter.isdigit()):
                    print('I found ',letter)
```

Text File:

```
fufge55gf6eh6h6eh6f9hg9hj
vgcg57vgr6vgn66cg4w3vgv78v
gv3c4ghc978c67654cchch
v4bci7r6ec5wgv
```

Output:

```
Enter file name: superpleasework.txt
I found  5
I found  5
I found  6
I found  6
I found  6
I found  6
I found  9
I found  9
I found  5
I found  7
I found  6
I found  6
I found  6
I found  4
I found  3
I found  7
I found  8
I found  3
I found  4
I found  9
...etc
```

I was expecting it to look like this:

```
I found 55 on line 1
I found 6 on line 1
I found 6 on line 1
I found 6 on line 1
I found 6 on line 1
I found 9 on line 1
I found 9 on line 1...etc
```

I need it to tell me the line each number is on (without separating the numbers that are together).

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal it does not. `.split()` with no argument splits on whitespace

Comment: You could use something like `for line_number, line in enumerate(f, 1):` Also, please don't remove edits that helpfully improve the formatting of your post.

Comment: It's not clear what your desired result is, what exactly you're asking for.

Comment: @Anentropic I already know how to extract numbers from the text files. I just need to know how to get it to tell me what line each number is on. I also need it to paste the output to a new text file.

Comment: ok, because your 'expected' example doesn't look like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the groupby function (form itertools) with the str.isdigit function to separate the lines on the alternating numeric and non-numeric sequences of characters.

To get the line numbers, use enumerate() in your for-loop:

```
from itertools import groupby
for lineNumber,line in enumerate(f,1):
    numbers = ("".join(digits) for isNum,digits 
               in groupby(line,str.isdigit) if isNum)
    for number in numbers:
        print("I found ",number,"on line",lineNumber)
```

output:

```
I found  55 on line 1
I found  6 on line 1
I found  6 on line 1
I found  6 on line 1
I found  6 on line 1
I found  9 on line 1
I found  9 on line 1
I found  57 on line 2
I found  6 on line 2
I found  66 on line 2
I found  4 on line 2
I found  3 on line 2
I found  78 on line 2
I found  3 on line 3
I found  4 on line 3
I found  978 on line 3
I found  67654 on line 3
I found  4 on line 4
I found  7 on line 4
I found  6 on line 4
I found  5 on line 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
    for line in f:
```

If you wrap that file iterator with
[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
your problem becomes simple.

```
    for line_num, line in enumerate(f):
    ...
                    print('I found ', letter, 'on line number', line_num)
```